# Is there any permanent non removable global storage available for the applications on each android device ?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I need to store the data on the android device and want to access this data from different applications(Through the services in background).

We can achieve this using the External storage. But it may possible that if it is removable then it will not be available when mounted to PC or removed. So, Is there any permanent non removable global storage always available for the all applications on each android device ? If so how I can access it.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how much data is it? single ints and strings or in the MB/GB range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But it may possible that if it is removable then it will not be available when mounted to PC or removed.

"mounted to PC" is not a problem on Android 3.0+, though it is on Android 1.x/2.x. And external storage is rarely removable on Android 3.0+ devices.

> So, Is there any permanent non removable global storage always available for the all applications on each android device ?

External storage is as close as you are going to get. This means that you may wish to reconsider your original plan. Depending upon the nature of your app(s), the answer may be that one app has the data on internal storage and is making the data available to other apps in your suite via a `ContentProvider`. This has more fine-grained security possibilities than does external storage.

Comment: So, that means there is no any comman place for apps to store data, right ? because if the External storage is the only option then it may possible that for old devices I need to implement other option.

Comment: @user2618875: "So, that means there is no any comman place for apps to store data, right ?" -- on the vast majority of Android devices, for the vast majority of the time, external storage will be fine. If you need 100% guarantees, then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Every device running android 4.0+ is based on [MTP (MEDIA TRANSFER PROTOCOL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) which means that if you mount your device to the PC, it will still be available to your application, so don't worry about it too much. You must have read some outdated articles about this.

**EDIT:** According to the answer of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), it's 3.0+ even, but devices running Android 3.x are so rare they are basically dead.

Answer (score 0):

File system storage will not help you as everywhere your apps can read/write every other app can read/write/delete, too and you end up in a similar situation as on the sdcard section.

BTW: Unmounting the sdcard section when connecting to a PC only works on onld outdated devices. Current devices just use the MTP protocol, which allows access from Android and PC at the same time.

If several apps are working together there a many ways for sharing data among each other:

1. Use the sharedUserId feature in each app (AndroidManifest.xml).
2. Make one "storing-app" that has one or more Provider for accessing the data from different apps. Secure them using a self-defined permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal storage with `FileOutputStream`, as it's explained [here in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

By default, those files are private to your app, but you can change that with the [`Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE) or [`Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE).

But please, be careful with that, as it can cause some security problems on your app. Perhaps you could use Intents or other ways to make that link between your apps.

For more information on that, please refer to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. For lightweight primitives (strings/ints, etc), you can write to system settings, which is hard to remove by end users.
2. You can expose app's data by using flag Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE.
3. Use ContentProvider for structed data. Use the authorities and permissions so that only your apps are allowed to read/write to content provider.
4. External storage, but as you said, is not reliable. The data on it are public and visible to all apps and also to end user. The data are easily deleted by users and some cleaning app.